# Batch file unable to run commands after launching putty

Tags: windows, unix, batch, putty, automation

I am writing a batch file `abc.bat` which is used to launch putty. I want the `.bat` file to go to a particular folder (in PuTTY), source it in `csh` and go to a particular path on that server.

I wrote the following in the `.bat` file

```
start M:\Desktop\putty.exe -ssh username@abc.com -pw password -m commands.txt
```

but it fails to read commands from the commands.txt which has the following

```
csh
cd /app/data/mig/
ls -lrt
```

The problem is, it launches PuTTY, asks for password and then doesn't do anything. Whereas I want the commands in the commands.txt to be executed on putty on login automatically instead of waiting for me to type the unix commands.

Comment: It's difficult to understand the question you're asking. Can you provide more details?

Comment: "but it fails": What does it do instead? Did you tried to use full path to `commands.txt`?

Comment: You have to write the entire command including parameters in quotes. Thus: "putty.exe -ssh username@abc.com -pw password -m commands.txt" and you need to specify a title too, because you are using quotes. see start /? for more info.

Comment: Your batchfile would look like this: Start "putty" "putty.exe -ssh ...." (where .... is the rest of the parameters)